# SQL LIKE with different wild cards pattern

Tags: sql-server, wildcard, sql-like

I have a form to get user input. In the Name textbox field user will specify how does he want the `WILD Card` implementation. For example if he types `abc` query should be:

```
Select * from Student where Name Like '%' '@Name' + '%'
```

If he types `abc*` the `*` should tell the query to return rows having name that start from `abc`

```
Select * from Student where Name Like '@Name' + '%'
```

If he types `*abc` the `*` should tell the query to return rows having name that ends with `abc`

```
Select * from Student where Name Like '%' + '@Name'
```

How can I write a query that would handle this type of user inputs? Will `Regex` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(100)='abc*'

if (CHARINDEX('*', @Name)>1)
  set @Name=Replace(@Name, '*', '%')
else 
  set @Name='%'+@Name+'%'

Declare @sqlText varchar(max)= "Select * from Student where Name Like '" + Replace(userinputtext, "*", "%") + "'";
Exec(@sqlText)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like below,

```
DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(100)='*kklik'

IF(CHARINDEX('*', @Name) = 1)
BEGIN
    Select * from Student where Name Like '@Name' + '%'
END
ELSE IF(CHARINDEX('*', @Name) >= 1)
BEGIN
    Select * from Student where Name Like '@Name' + '%'
END
```

Comment: Your answer will do the trick but if my stored procedure is already too long this would require a lot of more code too. Don't you think so?

Comment: Yes you are right, but I already mentioned here that you should try something like below and it always meant that you need to use little own logic as per your condition. BTW @Sahi has helped you after read my answer that's what I wanted you to do...

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @sqlText varchar(max)= "Select * from Student where Name Like '" + Replace(userinputtext, "*", "%") + "'";
Exec(@sqlText)
```

Comment: Its not any programming language dependent. I want it in SQL

Comment: It only works in `*abc` and `abc*` cases. It will return zero rows in case user types `abc`. If user doesn't specify `*` in the search box then it should query `like '%abc%'`